# "identifier expected". I'm trying to submit this form on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The error only occurrs with email, phone and messgae - why is it so? The datatypes used are `char` for `name`, `int` for `phone` and `varchar` for `Messgae` and `Email`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from ContactUs";
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds, "ContactUs");
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
    DataRow drow = ds.Tables["ContactUs"].NewRow();
    drow["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;         
    drow.["Email"]=TextBox2.Text;
    drow.["Phone"]=TextBox3.Text;
    drow.["Messgae"]=TextBox4.Text;

    ds.Tables["ContactUS"].Rows.Add(drow);
    adp.Update(ds,"ContactUs");
}
```

Comment: Exactly what error you getting???

Comment: identifier unexpected. compilation error.

Comment: Double check the spelling of your fields in the database, `drow.["Messgae"]=TextBox4.Text;` might be correct, but I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You are adding dot `.` while accessing/setting the value into  datarow .

**Solution :** You don't need to add dot `.` while accessing datarow.

Replace This:

```
    drow.["Email"]=TextBox2.Text;
        ^^ //remove this
    drow.["Phone"]=TextBox3.Text;
        ^^ //remove this
    drow.["Messgae"]=TextBox4.Text;
        ^^ //remove this
```

With This:

```
    drow["Email"]=TextBox2.Text;
    drow["Phone"]=TextBox3.Text;
    drow["Messgae"]=TextBox4.Text;
```

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: im facing this prob now. n sql serives are running.. i checked that.

Comment: @Princy: could you please show me the connection string?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cn" connectionString="server=SQLEXPRESS_PRI; database=Employee; uid=sa"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: you need provide the password try this: `<connectionStrings> <add name="cn" connectionString="server=SQLEXPRESS_PRI; database=Employee; uid=sa; passord=myserverpwd"/> </connectionStrings>`

Comment: i have not given any password. s

Comment: Try This: `<connectionStrings> <add name="cn" connectionString="server=SQLEXPRESS_PRI; database=Employee;/> </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.     i searched for this prob n changed my authentication mode from windows to mixed.. problem is stil lthr

Answer (score 0):

Are your column names correct? There's at least a spelling error (`Messgae` instead of `Message`).

Additionally, an array subscript or an indexer is not preceeded by a point. Remove the . between `drow` and `[`.

Answer (score 0):

add this code :

```
s.Tables["ContactUs"].Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
s.Tables["ContactUs"].Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
s.Tables["ContactUs"].Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(int));
s.Tables["ContactUs"].Columns.Add("Messgae", typeof(string));
```